# Multiple EC2 Instances outgoing/outbound traffic presented from a single/common IP (not using NAT!)

Tags: amazon-ec2, ip

I would like that outgoing web service calls from different EC2 instances will have the same origin IP address. Is there any proper solution for this problem which **is not defining a NAT** within the Amazon VPC?

All the questions I found over the www (see below) related always end-up with a NAT recommendation and I am wondering is there another solution but the NAT solution?

https://serverfault.com/questions/530783/multiple-outgoing-ip-on-one-amazon-ec2-instance
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=430341
http://engineering.silk.co/post/31923247961/multiple-ip-addresses-on-amazon-ec2

Comment: Give us the detail reason why you don't like NAT solution?

Comment: The reasons I am trying to avoid the NAT solution:
1. Single point of failure (unless I go and implement a high availability solution for the NAT layer itself and then I am again with the same problem of multiple outgoing IP's).
2. Bottleneck created by the NAT instance on the outgoing traffic.
3. Complexity of the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have requests come from a single IP address, then the machine with that IP address needs to send all the requests (obvious, I know). Therefore, it either needs to be the source of those requests, or requests from other machines need to route through that machine.

The easiest way to route requests through a single machine is to treat it as a NAT. This involves:

- Modifying route tables so that traffic destined for the Internet routes to the NAT server
- Configuring the NAT server to forward the traffic to the Internet and pass back responses

This could be done via a proxy rather than a NAT, but the result is effectively the same.

It is not possible to give the same IP address to multiple machines, since the return traffic won't know where to go. (Actually, it is possible -- see [Anycast on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast), but this is only for incoming traffic to stateless services.)